# C# Object properties changes when clearing Wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf, list, reference

I have a class which have a list

```
public static List<bar> tempList = new List<bar>(); 
public static Foo foo = new Foo();
public class bar(){
  public string name;
  public int age;
}
public class Foo(){
  public List<bar> lBar = new List<bar>();
}
```

I have several textbox controls: age1, age2
on `textChange` on each control a create a new object

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
   Following code: I want runtime calculation for a logic i did with age.
                   also need to create a new object using the inputs
------------------------------------------------------------------*/
age1_textChaned(...){
     createObj( );
}
age2_textChaned(...){
     createObj( );
}

private void createObj(){
     if(tempList.Count != 0)
           tempList.Clear();
     if(age1.Text != "")
           tempList.Add(new bar("name1", Convert.ToInt32(age1.text));
     if (age2.Text != "")
           tempList.Add(new bar("name2", Convert.ToInt32(age2.text));  
}
```

Then i have a button btn1 which will create the object then clear the content of textbox.

```
btn1_Click(...){
   foo.lBar = tempList;              
   clearFields();  //here lies the question, once i clear the fields,
                   //somehow it is still affecting the values in foo.lBar; 
}
private void clearFields(){
   age1.Text = "";
   age2.Text = "";
}
```

so when i do this

```
btn2_Click(...){
  foreach(bar b in foo.lBar){  //foo.lBar is empty i dont know why
    ...
  }
}
```

my current solution on `btn1_click` i have this

```
foreach(bar b in tempList)
    foo.lBar.Add(b);      // instead of foo.lBar = tempList
```

is the `foo.lBar = templist` causing these changes?

snippet is only a simpler version of an entirely different project.

Comment: You mention C# and WPF but did not add them to the tags?

Comment: After `foo.lBar = tempList;`, `tempList.Clear` affects both `tempList` and `foo.lBar` since they both refer to the same list. Perhaps you mean `tempList = new List<bar>()`? instead of `Clear()`?

Comment: There needs to be a working version of this example...something is missing. How about actual operations/bindings for an actual example program?

Answer (score 4):

Objects in C# are passed around by reference unless specified otherwise.

For example, here is the code you are running and how it works behind the scenes :

```
// create a new location in memory and refer to it using the variable tempList
public static List<bar> tempList = new List<bar>(); 

// add a new item to the list
tempList.Add(new bar("name1", Convert.ToInt32(age1.text));

// make the variable foo.lBar to also refer to the same spot in memory as tempList
foo.lBar = tempList; 

// clear the spot in memory containing the list
tempList.Clear();
```

That last line affects both the `tempList` variable and the `foo.lBar` variable because they both refer to the same location in memory.

The solution to avoid this is to create a new copy of an object in memory so the two variables are pointing to two separate instances in memory, and clearing one does not clear the other.

That is why your current solution works

```
// add the memory location of each item in tempList to foo.lBar's list
foreach(bar b in tempList)
    foo.lBar.Add(b);
```

Note that if you call `tempList.Clear()` it will only clear the memory references being stored in tempList, however the actual objects will still exist in memory elsewhere.

Also with this solution if you did something like this :

```
tempList[0].name = "A changed name";
```

it would change the `name` property of the item in the `foo.lBar` list as well, since they both share the same reference in memory.